# Changing image size from stream

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller

I've searched here for help with this, but nothing quite matches what I need.  I have an image that gets uploaded, and I'd like to change the size before it gets saved to azure.

So currently my code is:

```
public ActionResult UserDetails(HttpPostedFileBase photo)
    {     var inputFile = new Photo()
            {
                FileName = photo.FileName,                    
                Data = () => photo.InputStream
            };
//then I save to Azure
```

How would I change the photo.InputStream to 100x 100 px for example?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  There are *plenty* of tutorials online for resizing an image in C#.

Comment: I've been able to change the image size using WebImage, but then I only have image as a WebImage object and I cant save it with the:                  Data= () => WebImageObject..... doesn't work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is how I do it:

```
byte[] imageBytes; 

//Of course image bytes is set to the bytearray of your image      

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
    {
        using (Image img = Image.FromStream(ms))
        {
            int h = 100;
            int w = 100;

            using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(img, new Size(w,h)))
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    b.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    imageBytes = ms2.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }                        
    }
```

From there, I use a `MemoryStream` to upload.  I use blob storage and use the `UploadFromStreamAsync` to load to blob.

This is a basic view of it.

Comment: Is there a method to convert image format without saving it to disk? like change format in memory stream and then save to database.

Comment: @sairfan It's been a while since I wrote this, but looking at the code, it looks like the save is to the ms2 object which is a MemoryStream. I have not tested the conversion of this to a different ImageFormat, but I would imagine that you could change the format to another supported ImageFormat found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0